# Scheduled task not executing as planned

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler

In [windows-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) I have created a [scheduled-task](/questions/tagged/scheduled-task) .

It starts a program under `SYSTEM` user, on Log-on of any user.

The Action to perform is executing [RealTimeSync.exe](http://sourceforge.net/p/freefilesync/) with a rts.script

The action is running perfect when executed through a `cmd.exe` but nothing happens when the task is running.

Answer (score 1):

Use Logon Script ...

[Setting up a Logon Script through Active Directory Users and Computers in Windows Server 2008](http://www.petri.co.il/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008.htm)

[Setting up a Logon Script through GPO in Windows Server 2008](http://www.petri.co.il/setting-up-logon-script-through-gpo-windows-server-2008.htm)

[Assign User Logon Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx)